# IIS - VBScript to create HTTPS binding - is my way correct?

Tags: iis, vbscript

I would like to automatize the process of SSL certificate installation for **IIS 7.5**. The preferred way is to use VBScript. I work on the problem to create a new HTTPS binding and to bind correct certificate to this binding.

I actually solved this problem activating **Add IIS Management Scripts and Tools** role for my web-server and using script like this:

```
Set serverWebAdmin = GetObject("winmgmts:root\WebAdministration")

' EC8BCFF70983EA26BFEA087683329CB8C07366A5 is an certificate hash of the fake certificate 
' that i obtain from the staging environment of Let's Encrypt
' "MY" is the name of certificate storage
serverWebAdmin.Get("SSLBinding").Create "*", 443,"EC8BCFF70983EA26BFEA087683329CB8C07366A5", "MY"
Set newBinding = serverWebAdmin.Get("BindingElement").SpawnInstance_
newBinding.BindingInformation = "*:443:"
newBinding.Protocol = "https"

Set issuedWebSite = serverWebAdmin.Get("Site.Name='sitename.com'")
webSiteBindings = issuedWebSite.Bindings
ReDim Preserve webSiteBindings(UBound(webSiteBindings) + 1)
Set webSiteBindings(UBound(webSiteBindings)) = newBinding
issuedWebSite.Bindings = webSiteBindings
Set pathResult = issuedWebSite.Put_
```

It works well but before to use WMI to manage the server i tried to use (and expand a little) [an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding) from MSDN how to create a binding. I took the example on VBScript and added the declaration of certificate hash and certificate storage name (i checked also these properties, they are existing so seems to be possible to set them. I also checked the code of some open-source projects like WinAcme - written in C# - and they use the same properties).

So my code was looking like this (the part that sets properties of binding):

```
Set bindingElement1 = bindingsCollection.CreateNewElement("binding")
bindingElement1.Properties.Item("protocol").Value = "https"
bindingElement1.Properties.Item("bindingInformation").Value = "*:443:"
bindingElement1.Properties.Item("certificateHash").Value = "EC8BCFF70983EA26BFEA087683329CB8C07366A5"
bindingElement1.Properties.Item("certificateStoreName").Value = "MY"
bindingsCollection.AddElement(bindingElement1)

adminManager.CommitChanges()
```

It works BUT it only creates the binding and DOES NOT append good certificate to this binding. My problem is solved by the previous code snippet but I would like to understand: is it the second code snippent wrong? Is it possible to bind good certificate this way?

Thank you by advance.

Comment: “The preferred way is to use VBScript.” Itself is an out-of-date preferences, and even WMI should be used with caution. PowerShell would be your first choice.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it did not work with your bindingElement1 variant is simply because you can't add it to the bindingCollection, instead you have to add it to a method:

First part which you already had:

```
Dim bindingElement1 As ConfigurationElement = bindingsCollection.CreateElement("binding")
bindingElement1("protocol") = "https"
bindingElement1("bindingInformation") = "192.168.1.1:443:contoso.com"
bindingsCollection.Add(bindingElement1)
```

After that simply add:

```
Dim method = bindingElement1.Methods.Item("AddSslCertificate").CreateInstance()
method.Input.Attributes.Item("certificateHash").Value = "EC8BCFF70983EA26BFEA087683329CB8C07366A5"
method.Input.Attributes.Item("certificateStoreName").Value = "MY"
method.Execute()
```

Commit changes:

```
serverManager.CommitChanges()
```

So in total with some error-catching it could look like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim serverManager As ServerManager = New ServerManager
    Dim config As Configuration = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration
    Dim sitesSection As ConfigurationSection = config.GetSection("system.applicationHost/sites")
    Dim sitesCollection As ConfigurationElementCollection = sitesSection.GetCollection
    Dim siteElement As ConfigurationElement = FindElement(sitesCollection, "site", "name", "contoso")

    If (siteElement Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox("Element not found!")
    End If

    Dim bindingsCollection As ConfigurationElementCollection = siteElement.GetCollection("bindings")

    Dim bindingElement1 As ConfigurationElement = bindingsCollection.CreateElement("binding")
    bindingElement1("protocol") = "https"
    bindingElement1("bindingInformation") = "192.168.1.1:443:contoso.com"
    Try
        bindingsCollection.Add(bindingElement1)
    Catch ex As Exception : MsgBox(ex.Message) : End Try


    Dim method = bindingElement1.Methods.Item("AddSslCertificate").CreateInstance()
    method.Input.Attributes.Item("certificateHash").Value = "EC8BCFF70983EA26BFEA087683329CB8C07366A5"
    method.Input.Attributes.Item("certificateStoreName").Value = "MY"
    Try
        method.Execute()
    Catch ex As Exception : MsgBox(ex.Message) : End Try

    serverManager.CommitChanges()
End Sub

Private Function FindElement(ByVal collection As ConfigurationElementCollection, ByVal elementTagName As String, ByVal ParamArray keyValues() As String) As ConfigurationElement
    For Each element As ConfigurationElement In collection
        If String.Equals(element.ElementTagName, elementTagName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
            Dim matches As Boolean = True
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 0 To keyValues.Length - 1 Step 2
                Dim o As Object = element.GetAttributeValue(keyValues(i))
                Dim value As String = Nothing
                If (Not (o) Is Nothing) Then
                    value = o.ToString
                End If
                If Not String.Equals(value, keyValues((i + 1)), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
                    matches = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If matches Then
                Return element
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```